# Sigma above and below a value

Tags: java

I am trying to create java program which can sum up the numbers till n numbers and sum of values above the n number, n keep on incrementing and N are the total values
for example when n = 6 it should print

```
1+2+3+4   5  6+7+8+9+10  
1+2+3+4+5 6  7+8+9+10
```

I am able to sum up the values below n but not above n. Please help me find the error

```
public class Sigma {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 10;
    int N1= 10;
    int below = 0;
    int above=0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
         below = below + i;  // Sigma Below n
         int n = i + 1;        // n
         N-- ;            
         above = above + N;


      for (int j = n; j < N1; j++) {
         sum = sum - sum;
           sum = sum + j;
    }
         System.out.println(below + "\t No. " + n + "\t"+ sum);     
    }
}
}
```

Also if you can tell at what value of N1 will above and below be equal

Comment: Almost every line of your code has a problem, and it's not even clear what you're asking. Maybe the teacher's assistant can help you get back on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do `sum = sum-sum` which is `sum = 0` inside the loop. So you set the value everytime to 0 and then add `j`; So the value is always `j`. So replace

```
  for (int j = n; j < N1; j++) {
     sum = sum - sum;
       sum = sum + j;
}
```

by

```
sum = 0;
      for (int j = n; j < N1; j++) {

           sum = sum + j;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks do you know at what value of N1 will above and below be equal